# Vuejs router beforeEach : if state is true, run code, else load async data into state, then run same code

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, vuex

I'm using VueJS, VueRouter and VueX in my SPA.
I want my app to load some data at start up, required under multiple routes. This data is stored in the VueX's state.
Here's what I've done with my router, with explanations in the comments, hoping it's clear enough :

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
if (!store.getters.getStartUp()) { // a getter function returning boolean value of a state flag property named startUp, false by default and set to true when I have loaded the required data (in the created method of the main Vue instance (see next code example)

    const watcher = store.watch(store.getters.getStartUp, () => {
        watcher(); // cancel the watcher

        // Here is the code block I need to reuse
        if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forVisitors)) {
            if (Vue.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                next({
                    path: '/'
                });
            }
        } else if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.forAuth)) {
            if (!Vue.auth.isLoggedIn()) {
                next({
                    path: '/login'
                });
            }
        }

        next();
        // end of code block

    });
} else {
    // execute the same code block which is ran in the watcher.
    // what is the best pattern to do that ? 
    // a simple function defined in the beforeEach ? using Promises ?
}
});
```

and here is what I put in the created method of the main Vue instance :

```
created() {
    if (!store.state.startUp) {
        Promise.all([
            store.dispatch('getSomeData1'),
            store.dispatch('getSomeData2'),
        ])
            .then(() => {
                store.commit('setStartUp'); // set the state flag property to true
            });
    }
}
```

thanks !

Comment: In what line, do you get something wrong?

Comment: What's wrong with simply storing the whole reusable block in a single function?

Comment: @izumisy nothing wrong, I just question the pattern

Comment: @nit i was wondering if there was something more modern, maybe with Promises... but the simple single function does work.